# How to remove the character "*" in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, character

I have regressions tables in an Excel spreadsheet where the significativity is indicated with stars (*) characters. Those are attached to the number in the cell and the number of stars is not constant: sometimes three, sometimes two, sometimes one and sometimes none.

I would like to remove those asterisks such that I can use the number in the cell (it is currently understood as text by Excel because of the presence of the asterisk.)

I tried the following:

- search and replace the character * , but since Excel understands it as "everything", I end up with an unwanted result. I also tried variants of it: "*",'*'.
- Text to columns: but since the number of asterisks is not constant, it could not work. Besides, I would have to manually do it for an impressive number of columns so this solution is not practicable.
- Manually removing the stars is out of the question, too.

As an example, here is what I want to do:

A1=1***

A2=2*

A3=3

A4=sum(A1:A3)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The escape character in Excel is the ~. So, to find and replace all asterisks, search for ~* and replace with nothing. Please see the image in order to remove all * characters.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just a side comment for other readers: I always forget the quoting character - but found that it is also explained in the Help text of the Search&Replace dialog. so the quickest way to find it next time you're not sure is F1! :-)

Comment: Note that this also works for `~?`

Answer (score 4):

Use `~*` for the string to search.

If using Text to columns, there is a check box for Treat consecutive delimiters as one, and that is a perfect alternative for what you need.

Comment: Yes it works, but I have 20 columns to process. Hence, I'll for the trunc(substitute) version.

Comment: @user89073 - Text to columns should work for any number of columns, I guess. At any rate, you already have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I managed using this formula

```
B1 = TRUNC(SUBSTITUTE(A1; "*"; ""); 0)
B2 = TRUNC(SUBSTITUTE(A2; "*"; ""); 0)
B3 = TRUNC(SUBSTITUTE(A3; "*"; ""); 0)
B4 = SUM(B1:B3)
```

Comment: You could do all that within a single formula e.g. leave A1:A3 as they are and use this formula for the sum `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE(0&A1:A3;"*";"")+0)`

Comment: Sorry again, your method works only for text, right ? I want to generalize it to cells where numbers are stored as numbers.